# Are US persons subject to mandatory isolation if they have tested positive for COVID-19?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, public-health

(This is a edited version of a prior question that was considered "unfocused" so I am attempting to make the Q clearer)

Context: On Friday 6/26/2020 447 **new** cases of COVID 19 were reported in Duval County Florida. Across the US thousands of **new** cases were reported [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/covid-data/covidview/index.html). I assume that these persons/cases, if they were not already isolated in a health care facility, would be advised that they should/must isolate so as to prevent spread of this contagion.

Is there anywhere in the US where people who test newly positive for COVID-19 face mandatory (enforceable) isolation?

(Checking with my home state of Ohio, their State Department Coronavirus hotline tells me that they have not heard of anywhere in Ohio where persons that are newly tested positive are obligated to isolate.)

Do the contributors to Politics SE know of any mandatory isolation orders elsewhere in the US ?

I would very much like to see such a mandatory isolation order, if that is possible.

UPDATE: Duval County was used as an example only of a location that has experienced a significant increase in the number of new covid19 positive tests. If contributors have information from any other United States locations that might illustrate how local governments respond that would (even partially) provide insight.

Comment: The big problem here is that there are so many local jurisdictions that a meaningful answer isn't possible. I live in a suburb of Chicago which has its own health department. Go a couple miles south and the jurisdiction would be at the county level. Then the state might choose to take precedence if it feels local actions are insufficient.

Comment: @DonHosek, I am not seeking a universal answer (one that is accurate for all jurisdictions). I'd be satisfied with a response relative to even 3-4 jurisdictions, be they local or state. I'd like to be dissuaded from the notion that newly tested persons are told to  simply **voluntarily** isolate and that failing to do so has no legal consequence.

Comment: @BobE Which 3 or 4 do you want answers from? It's going to vary hugely across different countries, and probably within a country, and probably at different times.

Comment: @DJClayworth Limited to United States- I'd be satisfied with **any** examples where isolation (after + testing) results in an actual and enforceable order to isolate.

Comment: @BobE Not sure if this meets your criteria, but it appears to be an *enforced* order to isolate. https://www.kentucky.com/news/health-and-medicine/article241200076.html

Comment: @BobE Maybe refocus on mandatory isolation specifically to deal with the broadness of this question? Maybe "Is there anywhere in the US where people who test positive for COVID-19 face restrictions/isolation/etc"?

Comment: @DonHosek yes, this is helpful. Interesting that (in KY) a county judge had to declare a state of emergency to invoke "a little know statute" to enforce the health dept's requirement to isolate. This may be a bit unusual  the patient openly declared his refusal to comply with the request/order. If he was not so open, would have the county checked to see??

Comment: Many states have used an order modeled "after the CDC’s Model State Emergency Health Powers Act" for Covid-19 https://www.law.com/njlawjournal/2020/03/25/40792/?slreturn=20200530071000 It would not be unreasonable to list those states. VTR (See also https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMp2004211)

Comment: For all the details https://www.lawfareblog.com/quarantine-and-isolation-authorities-states-affected-covid-19

Comment: This appears to be a question asking "what is the law", not "why is this the law" or "how did this become law". This makes this a question fit for law.stackexchange.com, not politics.stackexchange.com. I will migrate it.